# Ruby: group_by operation on an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes that represent compounds stored in boxes.

```
database = [{"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound4", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound5", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound6", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound7", "Box"=>4}]
```

I would like to select a subset of the array, minimum by the number of boxes, that covers the full inventory of compounds (i.e., 1 to 7). Thus the result would be:

```
database = [{"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound4", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound5", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound6", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound7", "Box"=>4}]
```

I can use the following to group compounds per box:

```
database.group_by{|x| x['Box']}
```

I have trouble reducing the result so that duplicate compound names are removed from the grouped operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the problem is to find a minimal-size combination of boxes that includes ("covers") all of a set of specified "components". That combination of boxes is then used to compute objects of interest, as shown below.

**Code**

```
def min_box(database, coverage)
  boxes_to_compounds = database.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |g,h|
    h[g["Box"]] << g["Name"] }
  boxes = boxes_to_compounds.keys
  (1...boxes.size).each do |n|
    boxes.combination(n).each do |combo| return combo if
      (coverage - combo.flat_map { |box| boxes_to_compounds[box] }).empty? 
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

`coverage` is a given array of required compounds (e.g., "Compound3").

**Example**

Suppose we are given `database` as given in the question and

```
coverage = ["Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound3", "Compound4",
            "Compound5", "Compound6", "Compound7"]
```

An optimal combination of boxes is then found to be

```
combo = min_box(database, coverage)
  #=> [1, 2, 4]
```

We may now compute the desired array of elements of `database`:

```
database.select { |h| combo.include?(h["Box"]) }.uniq
  #=> [{"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>1}, {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
  #    {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>1}, {"Name"=>"Compound4", "Box"=>1},
  #    {"Name"=>"Compound5", "Box"=>2}, {"Name"=>"Compound6", "Box"=>2},
  #    {"Name"=>"Compound7", "Box"=>4}]
```

**`min_box` explanation**

Finding an optimal combination of boxes is a hard (NP-complete) problem. Some form of enumeration of combinations of boxes is therefore required. I begin by determining if a single box provides the required coverage of components. If one of the boxes does, an optimal solution has been found and the method returns an array containing that box. If no single box covers all compounds, I look at all combinations of two boxes. If one of those combinations provides the required coverage it is an optimal solution and an array of those boxes is returned; else combinations of three boxes are considered. Eventually an optimal combination is found or it is concluded that all boxes together do not provide the required coverage, in which case the method returns `nil`.

For the example above, the calculations are as follows.

```
boxes_to_compounds = database.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |g,h|
  h[g["Box"]] << g["Name"] }
  #=> {1=>["Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound2", "Compound3", "Compound4"],
  #    2=>["Compound5", "Compound6"],
  #    3=>["Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound3"],
  #    4=>["Compound7"]}
boxes = boxes_to_compounds.keys
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
boxes.size
  #=> 4
```

Each of the elements `1...boxes.size` is passed to the outer `each` block.  Consider box `3`.

```
n = 3
e = boxes.combination(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:combination(3)>
```

We may see the objects that will be generated by this enumerator and passed to the inner `each` block by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

The first element generated by `e` is passed to the block and the following is computed.

```
combo = e.next
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
a = combo.flat_map { |box| boxes_to_compounds[box] }
  #=> ["Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound2", "Compound3", "Compound4",
  #    "Compound5", "Compound6", "Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound3"] 
b = coverage - a  
  #=> ["Compound7"] 
b.empty?
  #=> false
```

As that combination of boxes does not include "Compound7" we press on and pass the next element generated by `e` to the block.

```
combo = e.next
  #=> [1, 2, 4] 
a = combo.flat_map { |box| boxes_to_compounds[box] }
  #=> ["Compound1", "Compound2", "Compound2", "Compound3", "Compound4",
  #    "Compound5", "Compound6", "Compound7"] 
b = coverage - a  
  #=> [] 
b.empty?
  #=> true
```

We therefore have found an optimal combination of boxes, `[1, 2, 4]`, which is returned by the method.

Comment: This is v. impressive, but does it mean that as database/coverage list increases it would take a long time to complete? To answer your Q. below, was aiming to use "group_by{|k,_v| k[:box]}.each{|_k,v| v.uniq!{|k,_v| k[:name]}}" to have each box reduced to a list of unique compounds. Then take the box with the most unique compounds into an array, and iteratively add the next biggest box, check for uniq after each addition, until all boxes have been added from biggest to smallest. Probably a messy way of doing it, but it seemed to work in my mind (of capacity < this problem!).

Comment: Yes, as the size of the problem increases the solution time increases exponentially. The alternative is to use a [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) such as the one you suggest. There are heuristics for certain combinatorial problems that guarantee finding a solution that is within a given percentage (say 95%) of the optimum. I am not aware, however, of such a heuristic for this problem Consequently, the worth of the heuristic often cannot be measured. Many a heuristic thought to have merit has been shown to actually be relatively poor when a better heuristic comes along.

Comment: This problem could be formulated as an [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).  It would have variables such as `x2 = 1` if box 2 is selected; else `x2 = 0`, an objective to minimize `x1 + x2 + x3 +...` and one inequality constraint for each commodity that ensures it is contained in at least one selected box.  For larger problems this would probably work better than what I proposed, but it too could be expected to bog down when fed sufficiently-large problems.

Answer (score 2):

With Ruby >= 2.4 we can use `transform_values`:

```
database.group_by { |hash| hash["Name"] }
        .transform_values { |v| v.min_by { |h| h["Box"] } }
        .values
```

Or if you have Ruby < 2.4 you can do:

```
database.group_by {|hash| hash["Name"] }.map { |_,v| v.min_by {|h| h["Box"]} }
```

---

***Key methods:*** `group_by`, `transform_values` (Ruby > 2.4) and `min_by`. See [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.com) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method when I update to 2.4.

Comment: @RDevelop I've updated my answer for Rubies < 2.4 too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `Array#uniq`:

```
database = [{name: "Compound1", box: 1}, {name: "Compound2", box: 1}, {name: "Compound2", box: 1}, {name: "Compound3", box: 1}, {name: "Compound4", box: 1}, {name: "Compound5", box: 2}, {name: "Compound6", box: 2}, {name: "Compound1", box: 3}, {name: "Compound2", box: 3}, {name: "Compound3", box: 3}, {name: "Compound7", box: 4}]

p database.uniq{|k,_v| k[:name]}
# =>  [
#   {:name=>"Compound1", :box=>1}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound2", :box=>1}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound3", :box=>1}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound4", :box=>1}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound5", :box=>2}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound6", :box=>2}, 
#   {:name=>"Compound7", :box=>4}
# ]
```

Or:

```
p database.group_by{|k,_v| k[:box]}.each{|_k,v| v.uniq!{|k,_v| k[:name]}}

# => {
#   1=>[
#     {:name=>"Compound1", :box=>1},
#     {:name=>"Compound2", :box=>1},
#     {:name=>"Compound3", :box=>1},
#     {:name=>"Compound4", :box=>1}
#   ], 
#   2=>[
#     {:name=>"Compound5", :box=>2}, 
#     {:name=>"Compound6", :box=>2}
#   ],
#   3=>[
#     {:name=>"Compound1", :box=>3},
#     {:name=>"Compound2", :box=>3},
#     {:name=>"Compound3", :box=>3}
#   ],
#   4=>[
#     {:name=>"Compound7", :box=>4}
#   ]
# }
```

Comment: Thanks @sebastián-palma. However lets say if Box1 and 3 were interchanged. The result would select from Boxs1, 2, 3 and 4. Rather than the optimum result which would then be Box 2, 3, and 4. I think I need to group everything by box, then find the unique compounds per box, then pick the box containing the most compounds, and then add the next biggest box (and so on), consolidating by uniqueness of compounds as each box is added.

Comment: Sorry I find it hard to describe myself. Lets say we have a Box5 containing all 7 compounds, this won't be selected by .uniq because it will find the compounds in boxes 1,2 and 4. The main aim is to pull all compounds in the least number of boxes.

Comment: Maybe this? `database.group_by{|k,_v| k[:box]}.each{|_k,v| v.uniq!{|k,_v| k[:name]}}` @RDevelop?

Comment: RDevelop, I don't understand how this answers the question. You said in a  comment that the first part of the answer is incorrect, yet the second part of this answer doesn't indicate which combination of boxes should be selected. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that original data structure.  Why not just start with a hash of `{CompoundX => BoxY}` since `"Name"` and `"Box"` are not really useful.  But if you're married to that structure, here's how I would do it:

```
database = [{"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound4", "Box"=>1},
            {"Name"=>"Compound5", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound6", "Box"=>2},
            {"Name"=>"Compound1", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound2", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound3", "Box"=>3},
            {"Name"=>"Compound7", "Box"=>4}]

new_db_arr = database.collect{|h| h.flatten}.flatten.collect{|i| i if i != "Name" && i != "Box"}.compact!
new_db_hash = {}
new_db_arr.each_slice(2) do |a,b|
  if new_db_hash[a].nil?
    new_db_hash[a] = []
  end
  new_db_hash[a] << b
end

new_db_hash
boxes = new_db_hash.values
combos = boxes[0].product(*boxes[1..-1])
combos = combos.sort_by{|a| a.uniq.length }
winning_combo = combos[0].uniq
```

The bulk of the work is just transforming the data structure into the hash of `:Compound => boxNumber` format.  Then you generate every combination of boxes, sort by the combination's number of uniq items and take the one with the smallest number of uniq items as the answer.  Not sure how great this would scale for very large datasets.