# Ruby iterate a function with its own output without mutating original input

Tags: ruby, iteration

The goal:Trying to optimize solution for the [alphametics problem on exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/ruby/alphametics/readme).

My approach: Rather than brute force trying every possible combination for all letters at once, I would like to try letters corresponding to the ones units first.  If a guess satisfies the ones units, use that guess as a starting point for trying the tens units.  And so on for as many places as the problem requires.

Rationale: Reduce the number of iterations overall by not wasting time with subsets of numbers that won't work for a subset of letters.

Here is my code that solves the puzzles but is very slow (puzzles with 8 letters take around 5-6 seconds and 10 letters MUCH longer).

```
class Alphametics
  class << self
    def solve(input)
      @input = input
      guess(@input)
    end

    def guess(input)
      letters_to_keys(input)
      left_most_digit_of_sum_max(input, @candidates)
      left_most_digit_is_not_0(first_letters(input), @candidates)
      generate_guess(@candidates)
    end

    def letters_to_keys(input) # create hash of letters and their possible values
      @candidates = {}
      letters(input).each {|ltr| @candidates[ltr] = (0..9).to_a}
      @candidates
    end

    def letters(input) # creates an array of unique letters from summands and sum
      (summands(input) + [sum(input)]).join.chars.uniq
    end

    def summands(input) #takes the input and separates summands from sum, removing the "+" character, returns array of "words" as strings
      input.split(" == ")[0].split(" + ")
    end

    def sum(input) # takes the input and separates sum from summands, returning a string of only letters
      input.split(" == ")[1]
    end

    def left_most_digit_of_sum_max(input, candidates) # the first digit of the sum has its value considerably constrained by the number summands when the sum has more digits than any of the individual summands
      if summands(input).all? {|word| word.length < sum(input).length}
        candidates[sum(input)[0]] = (0..summands(input).length-1).to_a
      end
    end

    def left_most_digit_is_not_0(letters, candidates) # the first digit of any number cannot be zero
      letters.each {|ltr| candidates[ltr] -= [0]}
    end

    def first_letters(input) # create an array of the first letter of each word -- for determining which letters cannot be zero
      a = []
      summands(input).each { |word| a << word[0]}
      a << sum(input)[0]
      a
    end

    def generate_guess(candidates)
      answer = {}
      potential_values = candidates.values
      letters = candidates.keys
      guess_index(potential_values).each do |i|
        dividend = i
        guess = []
        (0..potential_values.length-1).each do |ndx|
          divisor = potential_values[ndx].length
          if guess.include?(potential_values[ndx][dividend % divisor])
            next i
          else
            guess << potential_values[ndx][dividend % divisor]
            dividend = dividend / divisor
          end
        end
        if guess.length == potential_values.length && check_summation(letters, guess)
          answer = solution(guess, letters)
          return answer
        end
      end
      return answer
    end

    def guess_index(potential_values)
      index_length = 1
      potential_values.each { |vals| index_length*=vals.length }
      (0..index_length-1).to_a
    end

    def check_summation(letters, guess) # check that guess satisfies the summation
      nums = int_sub_for_letter(@input, letters, guess)
      summands(nums).collect{|x| x.to_i}.reduce(:+) == sum(nums).to_i
    end

    def int_sub_for_letter(input, letters, guess) # substitute numbers for letters in string
      string = input
      (0..guess.length-1).each do |i|
        string = string.gsub(letters[i], guess[i].to_s)
      end
      return string
    end

    def solution(guess, letters) # generate solution hash without mutating candidates hash
      letters.zip(guess).to_h
    end


  end
end
t1 = Time.now
p Alphametics.solve("SEND + MORE == MONEY")
t2 = Time.now
p t2-t1
```

I am trying to make this more efficient by reducing the number of iterations required.  I have done this by performing the calculation for each place (column if summation written vertically) sequentially.  Thus letters in the ones place that repeat elsewhere will have fewer potential values, leading to fewer permutations of guesses overall and thus fewer checks that the sum works out.

In essence the problem I'm running up against is this:
Given a hash of "places" with strings from the puzzle's terms as values, how do I iterate one set of values over each "place", expanding the set as needed to accommodate new letters in the next "place"?
To illustrate, for the puzzle "SEND + MORE == MONEY" you have

```
h = { 
      0 => ['D', 'E', 'Y'], 
      1 => ['ND', 'RE', 'EY'], 
      2 => ['END', 'ORE', 'NEY', 
      3 => ['SEND', 'MORE', 'ONEY'], 
      4 => ['MONEY'] 
    }
```

And after constraining the possible values for each letter based on position and number of summands, you get:

```
candidate_values = { 
      M => [1], 
      S => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      E => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      N => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      D => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      O => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      R => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
      Y => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
    }
```

I know how to generate all the possible guesses for each place, but what I want to do is generate all the guesses for the ones place, iterate over that set of guesses and check if the guess satisfies the addition for the ones place.  If it does, I want to take that guess, use it to generate a set of possible guesses for the tens place and iterate over those guesses in the same way.  But if NO solution is found for the tens place, it should go back to the iterations of the ones guesses.

FWIW, these are the methods I've been trying to use to set up the iteration:

```
def check_guess(guess, candidates, current_segments, current_letters, exp)
  nums_to_chk = current_segments
  current_letters.each do |ltr|
    nums_to_chk = int_sub_for_letter(nums_to_chk, current_letters, ltr, guess)
  end
  nums_to_chk.collect {|i| i.reverse.to_i}[0..-2].reduce(:+).to_s[-(exp+1)..-1] == nums_to_chk[-1].reverse
end
def take_a_guess(guesses, candidates, segments, current_segments, current_letters, exp)
  guesses.each do |guess|
    if check_guess(guess, candidates, current_segments, current_letters, exp)
      partial_solution = current_letters.zip(guess.each_slice(1).to_a).to_h
      exp+=1
      next_segments = segments[exp]
      new_letters = letters_to_chk(next_segments) - current_letters
      new_letters.each{|ltr| partial_solution[ltr] = candidates[ltr]}
      next_letters = partial_solution.keys
      next_values = get_potential_values(partial_solution, next_letters)
      next_guesses = generate_guesses(next_values)
      take_a_guess(next_guesses, partial_solution, segments, next_segments, next_letters, exp)

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I also spent hours on this problem (my solution was also brute force too).  I think you'll get better answers over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com though

Comment: Thanks, cross-posted to there.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum code in the question that demonstrates (runs) and shows the problem. Your code isn't valid and is full of uninitialized variables. While you gave us a link, you're expecting us to extract a working example just to help you, which wastes our time and affects our ability to help others. Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" will help.

Comment: Will have something tomorrow. My apologies for the misspeak.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No problem.  I think I might actually have gotten some insight from your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320165/ruby-group-by-operation-on-an-array-of-hashes/44323602#44323602).

Comment: oooh, this looks like a nice exercise. I should try it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but an extended comment. I would simply like to offer some suggestions for approaching the problem. (I would use recursion, btw.) I've spent an inordinate amount of time on this but what I have to offer is not very satisfactory, wandering all over the place, and incomplete. I've written quite a few more words and equations, and some incomplete code, but have stripped all of that out.

I have come to hate this problem. It's the type of problem where one can figure out a general approach to solving it in just a few minutes, but there are so many special cases and twists and turns that working up code to solve it is very time consuming and about as fun as having a root canal done.

**The problem**

The link gives an example of the question being addressed. We are given strings or arrays of capital letters that can be viewed as follows.

```
  S E N D
  M O R E +
-----------
M O N E Y
```

The idea is to assign a digit to each letter so that the resulting addition is correct. Here that is:

```
{ "S"=>9, "E"=>5, "N"=>6, "D"=>7, "M"=>1, "O"=>0, "R"=>8, "Y"=>2 }
```

which gives us the following.

```
  9 5 6 7
  1 0 8 5 +
-----------
1 0 6 5 2
```

**Observations**

For convenience, I will express this problem as follows.

```
arr = [["*", "S", "E", "N", "D"],
       ["*", "M", "O", "R", "E"],
       ["M", "O", "N", "E", "Y"]]
```

We can assume that "M" must equal `1`, as one would not write `0` in that position. Our beginning hash of known values is therefore

```
known = { "*"=>0, "M"=>1 }
```

It is more convenient to work with the following array.

```
arr.transpose.reverse
  #=> [["D", "E", "Y"],
  #    ["N", "R", "E"],
  #    ["E", "O", "N"],
  #    ["S", "M", "O"],
  #    ["*", "*", "M"]]
```

The first row represents the column in the 1's place, the second row, the column in the 10's place, and so on. Our search will progress row-by-row until we have valid assignments for all rows.

The third row (for example) represents two equations:

```
v("E") + v("O") + c = v("N")
v("E") + v("O") + c = v("N") + 10
```

where `v` gives the value of each letter (a digit `0-9`) and `c` is the amount carried from the previous column (`0` or `1`). The two equations correspond, respectively, to `0` and `1` being carried forward to the column to the left (with the next most significant digits).

The idea is to sequentially assign the digits `0-9` to "D", then for each assign digits `0-9` to "E", then compute the associated value of "Y", `v("Y")`. If `v("Y") < 10`, the carryover to the next column is `0`; else `v("Y")` is replace with `v("Y") % 10` and the carryover to the next column is `1`.

Suppose "D" were assigned `6`. Then the hash for the current location in the search tree would be

```
known = { "*"=>0, "M"=>1, "D"=>6 }
```

If "E" were assigned `7`, the hash would become

```
known = { "*"=>0, "M"=>1, "D"=>6, "E"=>7 }
```

The value of "Y" would then computed to be

```
v("Y") = 6 + 7 + 0 #> 13
```

(Note the carryover for the 1's column is zero.) Since `v("Y") > 9`, `v("Y") = v("Y") % 10 #=> 3`, `1` is carried over to the next column and `known` becomes

```
known = { "*"=>0, "M"=>1, "D"=>6, "E"=>7, "Y"=> 3 }
```

When the 10's column is processed the equations are

```
v("N") + v("R") + 1 = v("E")
v("N") + v("R") + 1 = v("E") + 10
```

but as `v("E")` is currently known, these equations reduce to

```
v("N") + v("R") = 2   (carryover 0)
v("N") + v("R") = 12  (carryover 1)
```

We may now assign different digits to `v("R")` (say), and solve for `v("N")`.

In the 3rd row we need only solve for `v("R")`. If that is between `1` and `9`, we continue to the next line; else we abandon that part of the search tree and go back to the 10's column. The algorithm terminates with a solution when the calculation for the first column (the last row of the above array) is successful; else it is concluded that there is no solution.

Suppose a column has letters `x`, `y` and `z`, and `c` (0 or 1) has been carried from the previous column and `v` is a function that maps each of these letters to a digit.

**Cases to consider**

Here are various cases to be considered.

*`x == y == z`*

This requires `v(x) = 9` and `c #=> 1`.

*`x == y, z != x, v(z)` known*

The equation here is either

```
2*v(x) + c = v(z)
```

or

```
2*v(x) + c = v(z) + 10
```

If `v(z)` is known, we can solve for `v(x)` like so.

```
v(x) = (v(z) - c)/2
```

or

```
v(x) = (v(z) - c + 10)/2
```

Suppose `v(z) #=> 5` and `c #=> 1`. The two expressions above evaluate to `v(x) #=> 2` and `v(x) #=> 7`. We would need to explore both of these possibilities. If `c #=> 0`, `v(x)` takes on a fractional value in both cases, so we would conclude that at this branch of our search tree `v(z)` cannot equal `5`.

*`x == y, z != x`, `v(x)` known*

Here we would solve

```
v(z) = 2*v(z) + c
```

or

```
v(z) = 2*v(z) + c - 10
```

Notice that `0 <= v(z) <= 4` and `5 <= v(z) <= 9` for the two expressions respectively, regardless of whether `c` equals `0` or `1`. Therefore, there is but one solution. Suppose `v(z) #=> 6`. Then the expressions evaluate `v(z) #=> 14 + c` and `v(z) #=>`4 + c`. Therefore, we need only evaluate the first expression. If`v(x) < 10`we set`v(x)`to that value and carry`0`to the next column; otherwise we set`v(x)`to that number less`10`and carry`1` to the next column.

Suppose capital and lowercase letters represent letters with known and unknown values, respectively.  equals the amount carried from the previous column (or or 1).

*Solve for one unknown value*

```
x + Y +  = Z      #=> x = Z - Y -        if Z > Y  (carry 0)
x + Y +  = Z + 10 #=> x = Z + 10 - Y -   if Z <= Y (carry 1)
```

The calculations for the unknown value occupying the other two possible positions is similar.

*Solve for two unknown values*

Suppose there are two unknown values represented by two letters.

```
x + y +  = Z
```

For `x` to be a positive digit, `y <= Z -` , which gives a range of values for `y` to consider, except when `Z = 0` and  `= 1`, where there is no solution. The other case is

```
x + y +  = Z + 10
```

For `x` to be a positive digit, `0 <= y <= [Z -  + 10, 9].min = 9`, meaning that `y` can be assigned any digit.

Again, the calculations are similar when when the known value occupies one of the two other possible positions.

*Solve for three unknown values*

If all three values are unknown we may sequentially assign the digit `0-9` to the letter in the first row, reducing the problem to one having two unknown values, which I just discussed.

*Special cases*

```
x + x +  = Z
x + x +  = Z + 10
```

If `Z -`  is odd or -1 there is no integral solution (for `x`) to these equations. If that amount is non-negative and even,

```
x = (Z - )/2
x = (Z - )/2 + 5
```

`0 <= x <= 9` for both of these numbers, so both assignments must be explored in the search tree.

If `x + Y +  = x` or `X + y +  = y` there is no integral solution. However,

```
x + Y +  = x + 10 #=> Y #=> 10 - 
X + y +  = y + 10 #=> X #=> 10 -
```

If the known value (`Y` or `Z`) equal `10 -` , the unknown value (`x` or `y`) can equal any digit.

The final case is where there are three unknowns, all equal. If

```
x + x +  = x #=> x = -
```

must equal `0` in which case `x = 1`, whereas if

```
x + x +  = x + 10 #=> x = 10 - ``
```

must equal `1` in which case `x = 9`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation of the problem.  One thing is that I think each letter must be assigned a unique value.  Your method for generating the arrays of letters per column using `transpose.reverse` is much more elegant than my method of creating a hash of segments of terms per columns.

Comment: Unfortunately the transpose.reverse method only works when each term has the same number of letters, which is not always the case.  I could add padding to make each term of equal length first.

Comment: That's a good point about the possible need to pad the first or second row with zeroes to make them the same length. You'll see that I already padded the column of the summand's most significant digit.

Comment: Yes, but by inserting a zero it makes it more difficult to check that each letter is assigned a unique value when one of those letters could legitimately represent zero.  I definitely agree with your statement "I have come to hate this problem."  I am going to edit the question shortly, btw, so that my question is hopefully more specific.

Comment: See my array `arr` and initial value `found`, Where the entry in `arr` is `"*"` I formerly had `"0"` (the character zero), which unfortunately looks  a lot like `"O"`. Any character other than a capital letter would do. I'll keep an eye out for your edit.